# How to convert a 2D matrix to transform

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, matrix, 2d, graphic

I'm working with Flash AS3.
If I have a set of transform data (x, y, scaleX, scaleY, skewX, skewY) I can convert it to matrix:

```
matrix.a = transform.scaleX * Math.cos(transform.skewY)
matrix.b = transform.scaleX * Math.sin(transform.skewY)
matrix.c = -transform.scaleY * Math.sin(transform.skewX);
matrix.d = transform.scaleY * Math.cos(transform.skewX);
matrix.tx = transform.x;
matrix.ty = transform.y;
```

My question is now I have a matrix, how can I convert it to transform? Is there any lib or framework have provide such function?

Comment: Another question is:I have two 2D DisplayObjects with transforms(x, y, scaleX, scaleY, skewX, skewY). One DisplayObject is another's child. How to calculate the child DisplayObject's transform related to global? 
From another side. I want to calculate transform concat(multiply).

Thanks!

Comment: From reading the documentation on transform, i suspect the answer to your second question could be some use of [Transform::getRelativeMatrix3D](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Transform.html#getRelativeMatrix3D()). I recommend posting a second, separate question if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Transform.html) on Transform objects:

`To apply two-dimensional transformations: create a Matrix object, set the matrix's two-dimensional transformation, and then assign the transform.matrix property of the display object to the new Matrix object.`

So the process of editing an object's existing transformation matrix should look something like this:

```
var newMatrix:Matrix = aDisplayObject.transform.matrix
newMatrix.a = 123
aDisplayObject.transform.matrix = newMatrix
```